# Firefox browser input problem. How to fix?

Tags: css, firefox, input

The slider in Firefox looked gray by default. As far as I understand, Firefox does not accept many css tags, such as `input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb`, as an example, I tried adding `moz-range-thumb` tags to the existing CSS, something like I managed to do it, but still the background of the slider is white, and this is only in Firefox.

How it looks after changes:
[image]

And my css code:

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: linear-gradient(
    90deg
    ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: linear-gradient(
    90deg
    ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: linear-gradient(
    90deg
    ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: linear-gradient(
            90deg
            ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    border: 1px solid #2497e3;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #a1d0ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    border: 1px solid #2497e3;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #a1d0ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: linear-gradient(
            90deg
            ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
}

input[type=range]:-moz-focusring {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-track {
    background: linear-gradient(
            90deg
            ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}
```

How i can remove this white background in Firefox browser?

Comment: What's your HTML look like? Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Maybe a CodePen/JSFiddle/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to adding `background` for `input[type=range]`.
you can set `height = 0` for `input[type=range]`.

```css
body{
  background:gray;
}
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    /* background:none; */
}

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: linear-gradient(
    90deg
    ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: linear-gradient(
    90deg
    ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: linear-gradient(
    90deg
    ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: linear-gradient(
            90deg
            ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    border: 1px solid #2497e3;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #a1d0ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    border: 1px solid #2497e3;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #a1d0ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: linear-gradient(
            90deg
            ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
}

input[type=range]:-moz-focusring {
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-track {
    background: linear-gradient(
            90deg
            ,#29bddd,#923ddd),#c4c4c4;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just set the `background` for `input[type=range]`.

Here's a simplified example:

```css
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    background: pink;
}
/* Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: blue;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    background: purple;
}
/* Chrome */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: blue;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: purple;
    height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range"  />
```